# Aligning matplotlib annotation to colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg, plot

I'd like to plot a colorbar, with a string(sequence) aligned to the bottom of it. I have a working example posted below, but it's not really an ideal solution because there are a few hardcoded values.
Are there any other/better/smarter ways that I could do this? Accommodating various font sizes dynamically would be ideal.

requirements:

1. The text must be selectable in a web browser as one continuous line (svg format in webbrowsers allows us to click and drag select matplotlib text)

   - I'd like to select the sections of the text. ie, if i see a particularly interesting region based on my scorelist, i'd like to select that sections and copy it to my clipboard
2. The text must align perfectly to the colorbar behind it.

If you were to make each letter an axes tick, they would no longer be selectable as a single continuous string (actually a newline separates them) which I don't want.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import array
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable


myseq = "AERGERGEREKLKLKLLLKKLWEWRKLEWRLWKERLKKLYKLTELWLKLRWELKHLW"
scorelist = [np.random.randint(0,5) for x in myseq ]

# SET FIGURE SIZE, Not ideal, but sort of works
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(len(myseq)/6.64175,5)) # MAGIC NUMBER?
ax = plt.subplot()
scorearray = array([scorelist,scorelist])

# Plotting the colorbar
cmap = plt.cm.rainbow
im = ax.imshow(scorearray, extent=[-0.5, len(scorelist)-0.5, 0, 5], cmap=cmap)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("top", size="5%", pad=0.04)
cbar = plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax, orientation='horizontal')
cbar.ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.text(-0.5,-1.1,myseq, size=14, name='Courier new')

# Use 1 indexing for human counting
ax.set_xticks([0] + list(np.arange(9, len(myseq), 10)));
ax.set_xticklabels(['1'] + [str(i) for i in range(10, len(myseq), 10)]);
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-0.5, len(myseq), 1), minor=True);

ax.grid(which='minor', color='w', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
plt.rcParams['svg.fonttype'] = 'none'
# plt.show()
plt.savefig("alignment.svg")
```

[image]

Basically I want to be able to look at colorbar representation of the scorelist, and manually select regions that I find interesting, and require the scorelist to align to my on-graph text nicely.

Answer (score 0):

*Note that the following does not actually produce the correct svg output. One may still use it for png output though.*

An option is to calculate the needed figure width according to the given text. So the idea is to first create the text with some font and size, then "measure" how large it is and according to that number set the axes width. Now the axes width itself is not directly available, but rather subject to the figure width and the margins being set, according to `figwidth = axes width/(margin_right - margin_left)`. We would then set the text width as the axes width.
  The text itself is positionned in the middle of the axes with center alignment, such that once the axes has the same width than the text they (almost) perfectly align.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

#### free input parameters ####
figheight = 4 # inch
subplotpars = dict(left=0.1, right=0.9)
fontsize = 16
fontname = 'Courier new' # need to choose a monospace font here

myseq = "AERGERGEREKLKLKLLLKKLWEWRKLEWRLWKERLKKLYKLTELWLKLRWELKHLW"
scorelist = [np.random.randint(0,5) for x in myseq ]

#### automatic plotting ####
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,figheight)) # at this point only height will matter
fig.subplots_adjust(**subplotpars)
ax = plt.subplot()
scorearray = np.array([scorelist,scorelist])

# Plotting the colorbar
cmap = plt.cm.rainbow
im = ax.imshow(scorearray, extent=[-0.5, len(scorelist)-0.5, 0, 5], cmap=cmap)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("top", size="5%", pad=0.04)
cbar = plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax, orientation='horizontal')
cbar.ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

# position text centered at middle of axes
text = ax.text(0.5,-0.08, myseq, size=fontsize, name=fontname, 
               transform=ax.transAxes, va="top", ha="center")
# draw canvas to fix positions of elements
fig.canvas.draw()
bbox = text.get_window_extent()
# calculate figure width according to width of text
figwidth=bbox.width/float(fig.dpi)/(subplotpars["right"]-subplotpars["left"])
fig.set_size_inches((figwidth, fig.get_size_inches()[1]))


ax.set_xticks([0] + list(np.arange(9, len(myseq), 10)));
ax.set_xticklabels(['1'] + [str(i) for i in range(10, len(myseq), 10)]);
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-0.5, len(myseq), 1), minor=True);
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(pad=10)

ax.grid(which='minor', color='w', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
plt.rcParams['svg.fonttype'] = 'none'
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now it's relatively easy to play with the free input parameters and observe the changes.
Note that in principle one could also automatically determine the padding between axes and text (here hardcoded to 0.08) and between axes and ticklabels (here hardcoded to 10 points); but as I don't know if that is needed I left that out.

Comment: Awesome I had no idea you could grab the figure width!
however this is slightly off on long sequences (2000+ letters) at least on my mac. One thing is that I have to do is use `matplotlib.use('webagg')` because I'm on a mac. but I don't think that's the problem.  Where did you get the values for `subplotpars` from? is a `left of 0.1` and a `right of 0.9` just default in matplotlib?

Comment: I don't know in how far it can be slightly off. Is it the same when exporting to svg or to png? The 0.1 and 0.9 are just my choice, but close to the defaults of 0.125 and 0.9. For larger sequences, smaller values of the margins would make sense. You could of course define them in inches and calculate the relative numbers on the fly, if you wanted.

Comment: The problem is definitely something different between svg, and png.  The png plot works perfect, but the svg plot is off, show here: https://imgur.com/a/PhQ1m it is equally short on the other side.  In the svg, the colorbar color also seems to be slightly off as well... weird.

Comment: Damn, thats bad. I didn't actually test it with svg so I didn't see this happening. I currently have no idea for a solution.

Comment: My **guess** is that it's just how svg's are rendered in webbrowsers/svg editors. the renderer maybe just picks its own 'Courier new' and thus results in a different width. However I feel as though 'Courier new' is pretty standard so I'm not sure why this is happening.   I asked the matplotlib people: issue #9276 on github

Comment: You haven't explained the issue very well in the post on github. Just saying that there is a discrepancy between png and svg and then a huge bunch of code is not easily understood by anyone. What you need to do is explain what you are doing (also possibly link to this question), why you are doing it and to be honest, the code is not a minimal example of the issue.

Comment: Sorry, my intent for the issue was to only see if I was saving my svg's improperly, or if it was just something intrinsic to svgs. I find it in poor taste to ask for help with a plot via a github issue, that's kind of what stackoverflow is for. But you're right I should have listed this post as a reference.

Comment: You don't need to change it anymore I guess, as the issue is still being understood. My point was exactly that: If you want to report about an issue saving a figure with text as svg, you don't need that huge bunch of code you have here. Anyways,back to the issue: Maybe it's time to look a bit out of the box and return to the requirement of selecting the text as a whole. There might be the option to decouple the image itself from the selectable text, i.e. show the letters as ticklabels, and provide the text differently (maybe as a new line or directly copying to clipboard via JavaScript or so).

Comment: Just to make sure i'm clear, I'd like to select the sections of the text. ie, if i see a particularly interesting region based on my scorelist, i'd like to select that sections and copy it to my clipboard.  I will add that to the post.